# Bash on WSL cannot find docker (or any command) even though it is in the path

Tags: windows, bash, docker, command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to execute a bash script on Windows with WSL1. This script contains a call to a command, like following:

`script.sh`:

```
echo $PATH
docker --version
```

after executing it from command line with `bash script.sh`, it returns the `PATH`, which includes the Windows path, including this Docker path:

```
/mnt/host/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin
```

Then returns `command not found`.

I do have Docker Desktop installed.

This also happens with any other command that should be in the Windows PATH.  I guess I don't know how to integrate the Windows path into bash?

Cany anybody help me to know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Deleted my old answer and posted a new one based on your edit.  It's much more clear now, at least, what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, try `docker.exe --version` but be aware of the caveats below in the "Details" section.

---

*Details:*

To summarize:

- You are in WSL1
- You have Docker Desktop installed in Windows
- Your `$PATH` shows that the directory `/mnt/host/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin` is in the WSL search path.
- Attempting to execute `docker --version` (or any other Windows command on the path) fails with `command not found`

As you seem to be aware, the Interop features of WSL (both versions 1 and 2):

- Append the Windows path to your Linux path
- Allow execution of Windows binaries

However, Linux does not have the concept of "file extensions" for determining whether or not something is executable.  Under Linux, you do need to type the full filename, *including the `.exe`* extension, in order for it to execute.

---

*Caveats*

In general, remember that Windows commands are *also* going to need you to provide *Windows* paths.  For instance, running `notepad.exe ~/myfile` isn't going to work because Windows doesn't have the concept of `~`, or even `/home/<yourusername>` or any other Linux path.  To Windows, that's going to be something like `\\\\wsl\$\\<distroname>\\home\\<yourusername>\\myfile`.  (Side note:  Don't create Linux files using Notepad anyway -- The line endings will be DOS/Windows instead of Unix/Linux.)

For Docker, in particular, note that you still need to run the Docker engine itself *somewhere*.  This can either be:

- A WSL2 instance that Docker Desktop creates and manages (the default, recommended)
- A Hyper-V virtual machine (the "old way")
- A remote Docker daemon that you point to via a `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable

In any event, it's not clear to me why you are attempting this from WSL1, since you'll still need for your Windows system to support virtualization in order to use either of the first two methods.

And for the third option, pointing to a remote host, you're going to run into an issue since Windows' executables can't (normally) pick up Linux environment variables.  You'll need to look into [WSLENV](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/share-environment-vars-between-wsl-and-windows/) in order to handle this, if you need it.

In general, while you are going to be able to get `docker.exe --version` to work in WSL1, be aware that you are likely to run into other issues down the line with more complicated scenarios.

It's much preferred to run `docker` in WSL2.  Docker Desktop will automatically link a `docker` (not `docker.exe`) into your WSL2 distribution which will be fully compatible with the Linux-side of things.